# Problem in python script for telegram bot which would count unique senders by specific timeframe

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot

I was creating a telegram bot which would count unique senders by specific timeframe (10m/30m/1hour/4hour/day) and records it in a spreadsheet file with three columns Group name, timestamp and number of unique sender but it's not working. What can be the problem.

```
import telebot
import gspread
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from collections import defaultdict

# Initialize the Telegram bot and Google Sheets
bot = telebot.TeleBot('6195710090:AAFzRZpv9xxxxxCLj4vFK51Gs70AmQVyKo') #this is random key

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('credentials.json')
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sheet = client.open('YOUR_SPREADSHEET_NAME').sheet1

# Define a dictionary to store the unique sender counts for each group
group_counts = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))

# Define the group IDs you want to track
#group_ids = ['GROUP_ID_1', 'GROUP_ID_2', 'GROUP_ID_3']
group_ids = ['https://web.telegram.org/k/#@Nepalisharenewsofficial']
# Handle incoming messages to count unique senders
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_messages(message):
    group_id = message.chat.id
    if group_id in group_ids:
        sender_id = message.from_user.id
        current_time = datetime.now()

        # Update the unique sender set for the group within the 10-minute timeframe
        previous_time = current_time - timedelta(minutes=10)
        group_counts[group_id]['10m'].discard(sender_id)
        if message.date > previous_time:
            group_counts[group_id]['10m'].add(sender_id)

        # Store the data in the spreadsheet
        store_data()

# Define a function to store the data in the spreadsheet
def store_data():
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    for group_id, timeframe_counts in group_counts.items():
        unique_senders = timeframe_counts['10m']
        row = [group_id, timestamp, len(unique_senders)]
        sheet.append_row(row)

# Run the bot
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling()
```

I tried above code and it's not observing the group message for 10 min. It's directly reading the json file firs